# How to find all the outgoing network traffic from a pod in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there any command or anything to find the all outgoing traffic from a pod.

Comment: Slight change in question
I want to find all the IPs to which outgoing traffic is going.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 1):

To find all the IP addresses your application is talking to, you will have to capture the network traffic on the pod's network interface. This can be done using [tcpdump](https://www.tecmint.com/12-tcpdump-commands-a-network-sniffer-tool/#:%7E:text=tcpdump%20is%20a%20most%20powerful,network%20on%20a%20specific%20interface.&text=It%20is%20available%20under%20most,%2FUnix%2Dbased%20operating%20systems.). Once captured, it can be easily read using tcpdump or on GUI tools like wireshark.

Incase you have the capability to install tcpdump on the running container, you can download and run it. Eg:

```
apt-get install tcpdump
```

Then capture and save the file in a .pcap format

```
tcpdump -w 0001.pcap -i eth0
```

To read and analyze captured packet 0001.pcap file use the command with -r option

```
tcpdump -r 0001.pcap
```

Rather than reading using tcpdump, you can export the .pcap file to your local workspace and open it on wireshark(which can understand pcap). This will give you a nice interface.

If you are not able to download tcpdump on the container then you will have to include it in the image.(which will add unnecessary bloat to the image)

Other options are mentioned below:

1. ksniff (will need to run privileged pod)
2. Ephemeral debug container (available from k8s v1.23 only)

**Ksniff**

https://github.com/eldadru/ksniff - Kubectl plugin to ease sniffing on kubernetes pods using tcpdump and wireshark

> Ksniff is shipped as a kubectl plugin that allows using tcpdump and
> Wireshark to capture traffic on a specific pod within a cluster.
> Ksniff uses kubectl to upload a tcpdump binary (packet sniffer) to the
> target container, and redirects the output to the Wireshark instance
> running in your machine.

This blog explains more - https://kubesandclouds.com/index.php/2021/01/20/ksniff/

**Ephemeral debug containers**

k8s (from k8s v1.23) provide a way to attach temporary containers to a running pod and run debugging utilities.

```
kubectl -n myns debug -i nginx-9456bbbf9-97gjc --image=nicolaka/netshoot –-target=nginx -- tcpdump -i eth0 -w - | wireshark -k -i -
```

–-target here is the container to be debugged.

This command will attach a container which includes tcpdump to the pod and capture traffic on eth0 interface. The captured data is then piped to wireshark of inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be of help: https://kubeshark.co/. You can view all traffic and run it on any existing cluster with little to no prep.

Comment: Please [add context to your link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, and then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to capture a pod's traffic network you can use a service mesh like [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/about/service-mesh/) or [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/)

I worked with Istio and you can have metrics for all traffic within a cluster , ingress and egress traffic